# HTML changing div color. Code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I want to change `#demo` border color by clicking on it, but it only changes when in css color is not given. I want to change my `#demo` div border color from transparent to red. Help me please :)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Paslėpti daiktai</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="pagrindas">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MxRlCi1.jpg" />
    <div id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" class="daiktas"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.pagrindas {
    position: relative;
}

.daiktas {
    width:50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:3px solid;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position:relative;
    left:195px;
    top:7px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    height:50px;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `color` changes the text color...not the border color

Comment: What changes the border color? Because this works when border color in css is not written.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's true. But the question is more interesing then it looks. The question OP is asking is why if `border-color` is **not** set in CSS, setting `color` behaves like `border-color`?

Comment: Of course it's obvious that one shoud set borderColor not color, not obvious why if I set `color=red` my border will also become red.

Comment: @dfsq I see you found the reference before I did. I was looking for something at MDN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very intersting question. According to [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-color) on `border-color` property:

> If an element's border color is not specified with a border property, user agents must use the value of the element's 'color' property as the computed value for the border color.

This is the reason why setting `document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red"` in your code makes border red too.

In your case, CSS rule `border: 3px solid;` does not define `border-color` property, only `border-style` and `border-width`, hence the observed behavior.

Comment: Which makes `currentColor` very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is almost correct try using this one

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Paslepti daiktai</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var element = document.getElementById('demo');
            element.style = "border-color: red;"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="pagrindas">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MxRlCi1.jpg" />
    <div id="demo" onclick="myFunction()" class="daiktas" onclick="myFunction()" style=""></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In your script you mentioned it as color but for the borders we say it as 
border-color.

The color in css is used for the font coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.borderColor
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.color
```

Course .color change color of text but not color of border.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_bordercolor.asp

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers you can find a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/649xuofp/

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById('demo');
    document.getElementById("demo").style.borderColor = "red";
}
```